# Insufficient privilege while creating custom view or table inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

I am getting insufficient privilege error while trying to create custom views and tables under `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` even though I tried to create it with `ACCOUNTADMIN` role which has all the privileges on all objects across Snowflake.

I searched around Snowflake documentation but could not find satisfactory answer to it.

Is it obvious? can't I add any custom views or tables under `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA holds information about objects in that database and is part of the Snowflake "application", you can't edit it or add anything to it.

Comment: if you want to add a view, just put it under some other schema, because a view can refer to any table from any database/schema using a full qualified name, so you need to be in the same schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to edit INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

[General Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes)

> Each **INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema is read-only** (i.e. the schema, and all the views and table functions in the schema, cannot be modified or dropped).